# How to programatically open PDFs in default PDF reader?

Tags: c#

i've got an PDF file and want to open it on clients desktop (so i don't know the directory of his default PDF reader)...

```
...
File.WriteAllBytes(pdfByteArray, path);
File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
...
```

seems not to work here...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try opening it like this:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(pdfByteArray, path);
Process.Start(path);
```

If `path` ends with some extension (like .PDF) that has an associated program with it will be opened with this program.

Comment: Also need to include "using System.Diagnostics" at the top of your code file.